# How to use jq with argument variable to replace value

Tags: jq

I want to add prefix and suffix in the existing value of JSON file.

Here is sample test.json file -

```
     "directory": [
        {
          "start_datetime": "1990-07-20 07:45:58",
          "end_datetime": "1990-07-20 07:45:58",
          "file_name": "N11",
        },
        {
          "start_datetime": "1990-07-20 07:45:58",
          "end_datetime": "1990-07-20 07:45:58",
          "file_name": "N12",
        }
]
```

Here is command which I'm executing -

```
export prefix="sample"
jq -c  --arg prefix "$prefix" '(.directory[].file_name |= "AWS_$prefix_\(.)_output.json")' test.json
```

Here is expected output -

```
     "directory": [
        {
          "start_datetime": "1990-07-20 07:45:58",
          "end_datetime": "1990-07-20 07:45:58",
          "file_name": "AWS_sample_N11_output.json",
        },
        {
          "start_datetime": "1990-07-20 07:45:58",
          "end_datetime": "1990-07-20 07:45:58",
          "file_name": "AWS_sample_N12_output.json",
        }
]
```

The command which I'm giving is not working. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: both the input and output file are invalid json files.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't expanded in double quotes. Use the `+` operator to concatenate strings:

```
'(.directory[].file_name |= "AWS_" + $prefix + "_\(.)_output.json")'
```

or use the string interpolation `\(...)`:

```
'(.directory[].file_name |= "AWS_\($prefix)_\(.)_output.json")'
```